# Background image does not show on iPhone/iPad

Tags: html, ios, css

There is a background image on our Magento web site that expands as needed due to the amount of content. It works fine on PCs and (hopefully Macs). But on any iOS device, the white background is not shown.

I have included two screenshots - one of how it looks in a regular PC browser and one showing how it looks on an iPhone.  (see next post for the screenshots)

Here is our site: http://tinyurl.com/arfpf7g

Here is a link directly to the image that is not showing up on iOS devices: http://tinyurl.com/bcovmvg

Thanks!!

Comment: This is how it should look (with the white background behind the text and photos. It is also above the polka dot background. See this link for the image (I can't upload images yet since I am a new member to this site): tinyurl.com/b6a7k3q This is how it looks on an iOS device: tinyurl.com/aphho7f Notice how the white background is missing. Also, what is causing that black line on the iPhone site to appear?

Comment: I had this same problem, which in my case had nothing to do with the file size of the images. The only fix I found was to use an img tag.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that iOS has a limit on the maximum dimensions of images it can load. From memory, it's 3 to 5 megapixels, depending on the device. For reference, Your image is 9.78mp (978 x 10000).

Your background image has absolutely no reason to be that big. It's 171kb and it's repeatable after about 10px. Cut out the top and it could be 10px high and you could achieve the same affect using `background-repeat: repeat-y` instead. Then simply apply the top of the background to another element.

Alternatively, that background image could be replicated in css using a box-shadow and a dashed border.

CSS:

```
.outer {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed #bde432;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WUpEF/

Comment: [Safari Web Content Guide (talks about max image dimensions](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html)

Comment: Yep that's the one I was looking for!